# Knowing when a map state props update

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following app in react and redux start kid

in a component, I am using a series of selector that are related to the same store Items :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
    itemsLoading: ItemsSelectors.getItemsIsLoading(state),
    items: ItemsSelectors.getCurrentItemList(state),
    fields: ItemsSelectors.getCurrentItemFields(state),
    columns: ItemsSelectors.getCurrentItemColumns(state)
})
```

When the store values changes, I would like to update my component state, by doing some calculation with the data.

I am using the following function

```
UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    const displaybleTable = this.getDisplaybleTable(nextProps);
    this.setState({
        items : displaybleTable.items,
        columns : displaybleTable.columns
    })
}
```

So everytime the store change, I get updated, and I update the component state.

The problem is, since I update the component state, I am looping in this function.

Also, I believe it looks a bit wierd.

IS there a way to know when the store value has updates in the component, so thatr component can do some personal data manipulation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of react do you use?

If I understood you correctly and assuming react version 16.8+, you can achiev this by using the [useEffect() hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). I assume your component is connected to the store using connect() from 'react-redux'. Then it could look like this:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const displaybleTable = this.getDisplaybleTable(/* arguments */);
        this.setState({
            items : displaybleTable.items,
            columns : displaybleTable.columns
        })
    }, [props.items])

    const getDisplayableTable = (/* args: any */) => {
        return ...
    }

    ...
}

export const MyConnectedComponent = connect(
    (state: RootState) => ({
        itemsLoading: ItemsSelectors.getItemsIsLoading(state),
        items: ItemsSelectors.getCurrentItemList(state),
        fields: ItemsSelectors.getCurrentItemFields(state),
        columns: ItemsSelectors.getCurrentItemColumns(state)
    }),
    {
        // dispatchProps ... 
    },
    (stateProps: any, dispatchProps: any, ownProps: any) => ({
        itemsLoading: stateProps.itemsLoading,
        items: stateProps.items,
        fields: stateProps.fields,
        columns: stateProps.columns
    })
)(MyComponent)
```

The second parameter of useEffect defines when useEffect() calls the first parameter, which is a function. So each time 'items' is updated in the store, the update will trigger useEffect which will run the code and sets the state of your component.

**EDIT:**

ComponentWillUpdate(nextProps) will not be called if some values in your store changes. ComponentWillUpdate only gets called if the props you pass to your component has changed:

```js
export const SomeOtherComponent = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <MyComponent prop1={val1} prop2={val2} />
    )
}
```

If val1 and val2 changes this would call ComponentWillUpdate of MyComponent (as far as I know, but I'm not sure).